# Adding color to the max value in a dynamically generated chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The jsfiddle link is here http://jsfiddle.net/MzQE8/110/

The problem here I feel is in my JavaScript.

I input values to the series object in a HighChart from an array.  On the array I am trying to find index and the value of the maximum element and then I am saving the maximum array element  back with this modification

```
                        yArr[index] = {
                            y: value,
                            color: '#aaff99'
                        };
```

So that It appears as a diferent color from the rest of the points on the graph which is a dynamic one. That is its sliding one.

Here is my code

```
$(function () {
 $(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart;

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                   //As this graph is generated due to random values. I am creating an Array with random values.
                    var yArr = [];
                    yArr[0] = Math.random();

                    yArr[1] = Math.random();

                    yArr[2] = Math.random();

                    yArr[3] = Math.random();



                    setInterval(function () {
                        console.log(yArr.length);
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        var index = findIndexOfGreatest(yArr);
                        var value = yArr[index];
                        yArr[index] = {
                            y: value,
                            color: '#aaff99'
                        };
                        series.addPoint([x, yArr.shift()], true, true);
                        yArr.push(Math.random());

                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 450
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions: {

            series: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random Data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: yArr.shift()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            })(),
            color: 'red'
        }]
    });
});

function findIndexOfGreatest(array) {
    var greatest;
    var indexOfGreatest;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!greatest || array[i] > greatest) {
            greatest = array[i];
            indexOfGreatest = i;
        }
    }
    return indexOfGreatest;
}
```

});

I feel my idea is correct but there are big holes in my implementation. I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MzQE8/350/

All y-values are stored in `series.yData`, so you don't have to create another array for that. Now just update point which is the highest one, and add new points. Something like above demo, code:

```
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0],
                        index = series.yData.indexOf(series.yData.max());

                    // mark first max points
                    this.series[0].prevMax = this.series[0].data[index];
                    this.series[0].prevMax.update({
                        color: '#aaff99'
                    });

                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random(),
                            color = null,
                            index, max;
                        if (series.prevMax && series.prevMax.update) {
                            // remove previously colored point
                            if (y > series.prevMax.y) {
                                series.prevMax.update({
                                    color: null
                                }, false);
                                color = '#aaff99';

                                // store max, which is last point
                                series.prevMax = series.data[series.yData.length]; 
                            }
                        } else {
                            max = series.yData.max();
                            index = series.yData.indexOf(max);

                            if(y > max) {
                               color = '#aaff99'; 
                               series.prevMax = series.data[series.yData.length];     
                            } else {
                                series.prevMax = series.data[index]; 
                                series.prevMax.update({
                                    color: '#aaff99'
                                }, false)
                            }
                        }

                        // add new point
                        series.addPoint({
                            x: x,
                            y: y,
                            color: color
                        }, true, true);

                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

im not to sure what your seeking but if i understand correctly you want the bullet marks to be a different color to differentiate from the others. i wont include source code because what you have included in your js fiddle is pretty advanced stuff and you will be able to figure this out no problem.

> > calculate (all total values added together / 256 + i) * 255 (or something similar)

the i represents the bullet increment in a loop. please for give the algorithm i haven't slept in 32 hours and i know its def. suggested you check it.

Oh.. kay here is the updated solution working out on paper
http://i966.photobucket.com/albums/ae147/Richard_Grant/Untitled-1_zps7766a939.png

I PUT A LOT OF WORK INTO THIS! so please!!! use it well -.-'

What is happening here is i drew out a graph with values going from 0 - 200 and i labeled the graph results 1 - 4, i also made this the x coordinates cause im lazy.

In the workflow RES = means results or X, Val = Value or Y

These are used to calculate RGB values and i solved the first 3 results. the first result tangent should always be 0 because any number divisible by 0 is 0, and any number multiplied by 0 is 0.

When i say tangent i mean the angle of the point by the 200, 0 value (invisible point). in this formula the angle would not be perfected because the x and y on the graph are not equal, one is 200 max and the other is 4 max. if i wanted this to be accurate i would have turned the tangent into a percent and multiplied it by 255. but i didn't.

I feel i have given you the necessary tools to complete your request on your own now :) if you do not understand how i did this or found this algorithm, just fall back to random colors.

Comment: Yes I am adding a different color bullet point so that the peak value could be distincted.

But what is this calculate (all total values added together / 256 + i) * 255 (or something similar). i could not get it.

Comment: ehh its hard to explain. basically you get the over all intensity of each result then multiply it by a color value. let me actually find an algorithm for this give me a second i will explain it much better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John doe, your question helped me. This is the function i used to change the color of the maximum value of my y axis:

```
function () {
    var maximum = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax; 
    var index = series.yData.indexOf(maximum); 
    chart.series[0].data[index].update({ color: '#aaff99' });
}
```

It may help other people too.